# What technologies would necessary to connect to a cloud server from a Node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, react-native, server, cloud, backend

I am relatively new to mobile development and would like to know further information about this specific topic.

I am working on a React Native based mobile application and am now getting around to implementing the back-end for this application. I will need to send data back and forth from the client (the mobile application) to the server (a cloud server). I am aware I can accomplish this with technologies such as a MongoDB database or a Firebase database, however, I would like to try to implement this on a personal cloud server.

How would I go about establishing a connection to a server in node.js so that I may send and receive data?

Thus far, I have looked the node library Express.js, but I am unsure if this is of any relevance as to what I am looking for in terms of a solution to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You will want something in the middle between the client and the database, so - sure, Express is a fine choice for that if you wish

Comment: @CertainPerformance I see. Would you happen to know if Express would be what enables me to establish a connection / make request to the server the database is stored on? Or would I need an extra layer to connect to the server first.

Comment: You would use your preferred database's Node library to connect to the database

Comment: I understand now. Your advice was much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you need to have a backend project for making your backend you choose Nodejs

[Node JS is a fast JavaScript](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/nodejs-tutorial/what-is-nodejs) runtime environment that we use to build [server-side applications](https://github.com/hrusikeshswain/NodeWeatherTest), but it does not know how to perform serving files, handling requests, and handling HTTP methods, so this is where express js comes in.

Express JS is a Node.js framework designed to build API's web applications cross-platform mobile apps quickly and make node js easy.

**Why Express JS?**

- Express was created to make APIs and web applications with ease
- It saves a lot of coding time almost by half and still makes web and
  mobile applications are efficient.

**The reason behind creating an express framework for node js is:**

- Time-efficient
- Fast
- Economical
- Easy to learn
- Asynchronous

After completing your backend project with either postgres or mongodb  database connection and node js you can deploy it to your cloud server and access it from the apis form the front end mobile or web applications.

Another thing I want to mention you can also create some web pages using node [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) as well.